# Name for a sum of dyadic vector products

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

> **Question:**
>
> is there a name for the following operation
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mx_iy_j^T,\ x_i,y_j\in \mathbb{R}^k$$ i.e. for generating a square matrix that is the sum of the cartesian product of a set $X$ of column vectors with a set $Y$ of row vectors?

The reason for asking is that it came up in the solution of a problem.

Comment: I haven't seen anything more fine-grained than just saying that it's the dyad formed from $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i $ and $\sum_{j=1}^{m} y_j $.

Comment: this is one way to write the singular value decomposition of a matrix

Comment: @CarloBeenakker do you have a reference, where that is explained? I think you have noticed that the sum of dyadic products is invariant under a permutation of the column vectors and also of the row vectors; I just want to be sure that my question didn't give rise to misinterpretation.

Comment: ah indeed, that's different from the SVD.

Answer (score 2):

The name for the above operation is 2nd rank tensor composition / matrix multiplication.

I will explain in a matrix language, since it is easier to grasp. Assume there is an orthonormal basis in which all vectors $ \mathbf{x}_{k},\mathbf{y}_{k} $ are expressed

If you organize the $ \mathbf{x}_{k}$ vectors as columns of an $n\times n$ matrix, say $\mathbf{A}$, and the $ \mathbf{y}_{k}$ vectors as the rows of another $n\times n$ matrix, say $\mathbf{B}$, then the expression above is exactly the product $\mathbf{AB}$.

This is based on the fact that the product of any two matrices $\mathbf{A,B}$ can be seen as: $$\mathbf{AB} = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \mathbf{c}_k^{\mathbf{A}} \otimes \mathbf{l}_k^{\mathbf{B}},$$
where $\mathbf{c}_k^{\mathbf{A}}$ are the columns of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{l}_k^{\mathbf{B}}$ are the rows of $\mathbf{B}$, while $N$ denotes the number of columns of $A$ (the same as the number of rows of $B$, such that the multiplication could be performed)

Comment: Did you mean the rows of $B$ are $y_k^T$?

Comment: You seem to be assuming $k=n=m$ (in the nomenclature of the OP)? I don't see that in the OP.